# How to display this chart using jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an array of date and an array of values but they don't have the same size :/
for each date i have many values.
So please i need your help to display this chart with:
  TimePeriodValues serie = new TimePeriodValues("r en fonction de t");
any ideas ???

Comment: Please add some code so that we can clearly understand your problem.

Comment: TimePeriodValues serie = new TimePeriodValues("r en fonction de t");
           TimePeriodValuesCollection dataset1 = new TimePeriodValuesCollection();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j< res4.length; j++) {
             serie.add(new Hour(v2.elementAt(i).getHours(),v2.elementAt(i).getDate(),(v2.elementAt(i).getMonth()+1),2015), Double.parseDouble(res4[j]));
                 }  
        }
        dataset1.addSeries(serie);
        //dataset.addSeries(series1);

Comment: @Makni: Code in comments is hard to read; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.